# HTML: sanitize a set of tags but allow all tags in <code> blocks

Tags: django, markdown, html-sanitizing

I'm using Django+Markdown for processing user input. Text produced by the markdown filter need to be 'safe' and is not protected by django's auto-escape mechanism, so I have to escape user input myself. This is how I do it now:

```
{{ text|force_escape|markdown:"codehilite" }}
```

However, if `text` contains something that would be marked as `<code>` by markdown, it is escaped as well and the output would be pretty ugly(e.g., '<' is displayed as `&lt;` in `<code>`). For example, if

```
text = u'''
       <script>alert("I'm not working 'cause I'll be escaped")</script>
       The following would be marked as a code block:

           <script>alert("not xss 'cause I'm in <code>")</script>

'''
```

Using the filter mentioned above, the produced text is:

```
<p>
    &lt;script&gt;alert("I'm not working 'cause I'll be escaped")&lt;/script&gt;
    The following would be marked as a code block:
</p>
<pre class="codehilite">
    <code>
        &amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert(&amp;quot;not xss &amp;#39;cause I&amp;#39;m in &amp;lt;code&amp;gt;&amp;quot;)&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

What I what is:

```
<p>
    &lt;script&gt;alert("I'm not working 'cause I'll be escaped")&lt;/script&gt;
    The following would be marked as a code block:
</p>
<pre class="codehilite">
    <code>
        <script>alert("not xss 'cause I'm in <code>")</script>
    </code>
</pre>
```

I'm thinking about using BeautifulSoup to get the `<code>` blocks produced by markdown and reverse-escape their content. But `soup.code.text` returns only the 'text', excluding the tags. so I couldn't get my hands on any of the `<,>,',",&`s in it..

Comment: This is wrong. `&gt;` or `&lt;` inside a code block means that it was *double-escaped*. You do not want what you think you want. All code instead code blocks *needs to be escaped*.

Comment: @Xeoncross You're right, it gets double-escaped. Once is done by `force_escape` and the second by the browser because it's a code block.. What I want to do is to keep code blocks free from `force_escape`.

Comment: @burrcat, browsers do *not* escape HTML inside of code blocks. That is a common miss-understanding. Something *else* is escaping the code a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the input before passing it to Markdown.  As you found, this breaks user input in some cases.  And, it doesn't ensure security: consider, e.g., "`[clickme](javascript:alert%28%22xss%22%29)`".

Instead, the correct approach is to use Markdown in its safe mode.  I've written [elsewhere](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14674/971) about how to do so, but the short version in Django is to use something like `{{ text | markdown:"safe" }}`.  (Alternatively, you can apply a HTML sanitizer, like HTML Purifier, to the output of the Markdown processor.)